# m(b − a) integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

Given:
Suppose that $f$ is a bounded function defined on [a, b] and that $P = \{x_0, …, x_n\}$
is a partition of [a, b]. For each i = 1, …, n we let $$M_i(f) = sup \{ f (x) : x ∈ [x_{i –1}, x_i]\}$$ and 
$$m_i(f) = inf\{ f (x) : x ∈ [x_{i –1}, x_i]\}$$
When only one function is under consideration, we may abbreviate these to
$M_i$ and $m_i$, respectively.
Let $ \Delta x_i  = x_i – x_{i-1}$ for (i = 1,…, n), we define the upper sum of $f$ with respect to partition $P$ to be $$U(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n M_i\Delta x_i$$
and the lower sum of $f$ with respect to $P$ to be $$L(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i\Delta x_i$$

Since we are assuming that $f$ is a bounded function on [a, b], there exist
numbers $m$ and $M$ such that $m ≤ f (x) ≤ M$ for all $x$ ∈ [a, b]. Thus for any
partition $P$ of [a, b] we have
$$m(b − a) ≤ L( f ,P) ≤ U( f ,P) ≤ M(b − a).$$

My Question:
What does $m(b-a)$ (and $M(b-a)$) refer to? As far as I can tell $m$ is the minimum value of a function $f$ and $M$ the maximum value of a function $f$.

Edit: I understand that $b-a = (\Delta x_1+...+\Delta x_i)$. I just do not understand where this $m()$ and $M()$ come from.

Edit 2: The question has been answered. I misinterpreted $m(b-a)$ as a function instead of $m \cdot (b-a)$

Comment: $m(b-a) = m \cdot (b-a)$  is simply the *product* of the numbers $m$  and $ b-a$.

Comment: $m\leqslant m_i$ and $M\geqslant M_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem. $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\Delta x_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^n m \Delta x_i = m \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta x_i = m \cdot (b-a)$. There is no $m()$ function, the parentheses are only there to specify the order of operations.

Comment: @MartinR I believe that I misinterpreted the way $m(b-a)$ and $M(b-a)$ were written. Now that I read it as $m \cdot (b-a)$ I understand the statement that has been made in the book. Thank you.